# I can't get post id in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I use this code to get Post's id in wordpress, but it returns empty. What is wrong here?

```
 $post_id=get_the_ID();
 echo 'Post ID: ' . $post_id. "\n";
```

Comment: does it contain any posts?

Comment: `get_the_ID()` only works inside the Loop.  depending on the context you will have to get it another way... please show us more code and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Wordpress [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) for the `$post_id` says: This tag must be within The Loop.

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            // your code here
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

More on this: http://www.thewordpressblog.com/basics/get-post-id-inside-and-outside-the-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so I writ so:

```
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $pid=get_the_ID();
    echo "Post ID: ".$pid;
    endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

And getting IDs for all posts in the page.. but I need just one post's ID.